Error al migrar posts de Wordpress a Drupal 10
Hola Intento migrar de WordPress a Drupal, descargue mi contenido con la opción de WordPress Export y en Drupal instale los módulos migrate y WordPress migrate, al ejecutar el import en Drupal me arroja el siguiente error:

Drupal\migrate\MigrateException: Error message: The scheme 'public' is
not supported. at public://

Cabe mencionar que en el sistema de archivos públicos tengo la siguiente ruta sites/default/files
las carpetas tienen los permisos 755
No se que mas pueda ser, me podrían ayudar por favor.
